# OSError: pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured

Tags: python, stdin

I am facing a problem in my exercism python exercise 2. I have written the program and it is working fine but when i submit it on exercism it says "OSError: pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured!  Consider using `-s`."   then i checked on visual studio and it is working fine. i have googled it but i was unable to solve this problem. Is there any clue for solving this ?

wrote a program on exercism but it is giving oserror but working fine on visual studio